# Biblatex APA6 Natbib - No ampersand with \citealp

Tags: biblatex, natbib, apa6

When applying `biblatex` with `natbib` and `apa6` there is a weired difference between using `\citep` (`\citet`) and `\citealp` regarding the ampersand when citing multiple authors. With `\citep` (`\citet`) there is an ampersand (&) as required, however with `\citealp` there is an "and". Does anyone know how one can apply the `\citealp` option with ampersand?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=apa6,isbn=false,doi=true,eprint=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \citep{Lee.2011b}
    
    \citealp{Lee.2011c}
    
    \begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    
    @article{Lee.2011b,
        author = {Lee, Jeoung-Hak and Kim, Hyun-Duck and Ko, Yong Jae and Sagas, Michael},
        year = {2011},
        title = {The influence of service quality on satisfaction and intention: A gender segmentation strategy},
        pages = {54--63},
        pagination = {page},
        volume = {14},
        issn = {1441-3523},
        journaltitle = {Sport Management Review},
        number = {1},
        abstract = {}
    }
    
    @article{Lee.2011c,
        author = {Lee, Jeoung-Hak and Kim, Hyun-Duck and Ko, Yong Jae and Sagas, Michael},
        year = {2011},
        title = {The influence of service quality on satisfaction and intention: A gender segmentation strategy},
        pages = {54--63},
        pagination = {page},
        volume = {14},
        issn = {1441-3523},
        journaltitle = {Sport Management Review},
        number = {1},
        abstract = {}
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    
        \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `biblatex`'s `natbib` compatibility module is just a very thin wrapper bolted onto `biblatex`, I wouldn't expect it to work completely like `natbib` with all styles, especially with more specialised ones.

`\citealp` is defined in terms of `\cite`. But for `biblatex-apa6` (and `biblatex-apa`) it would make much more sense to define it in terms of `\nptextcite`, so that's what you can do.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=apa6,isbn=false,doi=true,eprint=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\citealp}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}}%
     \nptextcite}
    {\nptextcite}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \citep{sigfridsson}
    
  \citealp{sigfridsson}
    
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)//Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998]